Two guys break in and take a man hostage
I think it's a 2015 American movie. Two guys breaking into a house. One has a gun. They tie up the owner who happens to be the father of one of the intruders. That intruder is taking revenge for leaving his mom. The other intruder seems autistic.
We see a person is mowing the lawn and then knocks on the door to get paid once he is done. Owner somehow manages to write "call 911" on a dollar bill and tries to give it to the gardener. But the gardener politely refuses saying he already paid him too much or something. (Owner is at gunpoint all this time,standing behind the door.) The intruder gets suspicious and checks the dollar and finds the writing.
Owner's daughter comes home and also gets tied up. In the end the autistic guy shoots the other. I think it was an Indie film. Also, the poster had two people facing a house with one having a gun in his hand.

Approximately what year? American film? And what does "A gardener knocks the door for cash," mean? Knocks on the door" For what cash? Any other details like plot points, actors, settings, wold help. Maybe pop over and take the Tour to get a better idea of how to ask and answer questions. We're not a typical discussion forum. Don't be discouraged, we were all new here at some point. (It'll also get you your first badge real quick.)

@MeatTrademark Thank you for the suggestions. I think its a 2015 movie., American 2) we see a person is mowing the lawn and then knocks on the door to get paid once he is done. Owner somehow manages to write "call 911" on a dollar bill and tries to give to the gardener. But the gardener politely refuses saying he already paid him too much or something.. (Owner is at gunpoint all this time,standing behind the door) The intruder gets suspicious and checks the dollar and finds the writing.This is all i remember. Also the poster had two people facing a house with one having a gun in his hand.

You should edit these and any other memories into your question.

This movie Bad is Bad seems to tick some, but not all of the boxes you have described:
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1732563/
Can't really find a plot synopsis but it looks like one of the boys is designed to be strange or autistic, one of the boys has a gun, it looks like a gardener is coming to the house at one point and the movie poster looks similar to what you described.
It however is from 2011, not 2015, so this might not be your movie.

